# How can I expose statistics about resources through a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, laravel

I'm building an API for my web app and have got as far as exposing all the resources my app uses, e.g. `/users`, `/roles`, `/posts` etc with no problem.

**I'm now stuck on how to expose statistics about some of these resources in a RESTful way.** It doesn't seem right to have a `statistics` resource, as `GET /statistics/1` could be anything, and the results will likely change each request, as the stats are real-time, so it will not be cacheable.

Background:

For each of the `/users` in the system, the app periodically queries Steam's API for the `/games` they are playing, and the `/servers` they are playing it on, and stores this information along with a timestamp in the `/states` resource.

This information is aggregated to show a tally of the most popular games and servers on the `/statistics/games/current-usage` and `statistics/servers/current-usage` standard HTML pages. Illustrative screenshots: [servers](http://zeropingheroes.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/lanager/servers.png), [games](http://zeropingheroes.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/lanager/games.png) (taken at different times).

EDIT: Sample data for the basic resources

```
"state": {
    "id": 292002,
    "user_id": 135,
    "game_id": 24663,
    "server_id": 135,
    "created_at":"2014-06-22 21:12:03"
},
"user": {
    "id": 112,
    "username": "ilumos",
    "steam_id_64": "76561197970613738"
},
"server": {
    "id": 135,
    "application_id": 24663,
    "name": null,
    "address": "192.168.241.65",
    "port": "0"
},
"game": {
    "id": 24663,
    "name": "DEFCON",
    "steam_app_id": 1520
}
```

**EDIT 2: Does REST permit endpoints that use a timestamp as the resource identifier?** e.g:

`GET /statistics/1403681498/games` to get a response like this:

```
[
    "game": {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "DEFCON",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 7654,
                "username": "daryl",
                "server": {
                    "id": 127,
                    "ip": "123.123.123.123",
                    "port": "27960"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 135,
                "username": "ilumos"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: REST doesn't care about what the ID is. As long as you can use it to uniquely identify the resource, you're good. Be careful, though, because timestamps can be tricky if the client clock and the server clock are in different time zones and/or are not synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go with creating a `usage` resosuce as all of these statistics will be the usage of other resources, either "right now" or at a historic point in time.

My URIs will look like this:
    GET /usage/{resource-name}/{resource-id}

```
GET /usage/games/                           collection of games in use right now (with user totals)
GET /usage/servers/                         collection of servers in use right now
GET /usage/games/?timestamp=1234567890      collection of games in use at {timestamp}

GET /usage/games/1                          usage of game with id 1 right now
GET /usage/games/1?timestamp=1234567890     usage of game with id 1 at {timestamp}
GET /usage/games/?user_id=123               usage of game with id 1 filtered to show only user with id 123
```

And in future I can extend the resource to for example return usage for electricity usage

```
GET /usage/phases/                          collection of phases in use right now (with power draw totals)
GET /usage/phases/1                         usage of phase with id 1 right now
GET /usage/phases/?timestamp=1234567890     collection of phases in use at {timestsamp} (with power draw totals)
```

Unless there's something inhernatly un-RESTful about this it seems to be the most fitting way of exposing this info.

Answer (score 7):

You have a variety of not-wholly-unreasonable options.

You can

1. include statistics with each response. Will all clients want
   statistics? Are there a lot of statistics? Maybe something like GET /games?orderBy=numPlayers-&offset=0&limit=10 would work if all you're tracking is number of players.
2. have a `/statistics/{statisticId}` endpoint. This is not inherently unRESTful.
3. have a `/games/{gameId}/statistics` endpoint.
4. have a `/statistics/games/{gameId}` endpoint.

Really, there's no way for us to tell you what the best way is to implement this because we don't have enough information.

Comment: It's unlikely that every client will want stats with each response at the moment but that's given me some inspiration... However options 3 & 4 look good - would adding a time parameter be permissible? Defaulting the parameter to "now" if it is missing?

Comment: I'd advise option three, it's the most logical as I see it. You get `/games/{gameID}` and that resource links you to the stats at `/game/{gameID}/stats`. And yes, perfectly fine to add a timestamp on the end, as either `.../{timestamp}` or `...?time={timestamp}`

Comment: I agree on the timestamp, though I'd suggest the ?time={timestamp} option.